# Example of Artinian module which has infinitely many maximal submodules not isomorphic to each other

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> I'm looking for an Artinian module which has infinitely many maximal submodules not isomorphic to each other.

I guess I can find it over a matrix ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be an infinite field.  Let the ring be $k[d/dx,d/dy]$, and let the module be affine linear functions (i.e., of the form $ax+by+c$ for $a,b,c$ in $k$), with the ring acting in the natural way.  There is a maximal submodule for each possible slope of line, and they are all non-isomorphic.